# Optimizing Vehicle Routing with Multiple Optional Locations

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

I have a question regarding the Vehicle Routing Problem in Optaplanner. So far, I understand that there is a method called getRoute() in the Vehicle class, which contains all the locations to be visited. I suspect that changing or optimizing the order of these locations is related to this method. Now, I want to perform an optimization where I can't use the getRoute() method because I have multiple locations that are not necessarily part of the route but could be part of it.  For example, I have 4 packages to deliver and 8 empty locations. When delivering these packages, I want to select the locations in a way that:
1.achieve the shortest route.
2. do not exceed the vehicle's capacity.

In this example, I cannot solve it using the getRoute() method because it includes all the locations to be visited. However, I suspect that the constraints for total distance and capacity are linked to the getRoute(). I'm not sure if a solution is possible without using such a method. Has anyone tried something similar and knows if this is theoretically possible?

I have randomly assigned locations for the orders to available locations from the list and then passed these orders with their assigned positions to the @PlanningListVariable. Afterward, I activated the constraints but noticed that they had no impact on the solution. The order of the jobs was still the same as implemented in the job list.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for **overconstrained planning**.

In Timefold ([continuation of OptaPlanner](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork) by the OptaPlanner team) we intend to support `nullable=true` like functionality on `@PlanningListVariable` to indicate that assigning visits is optional.

[You can track the status of that RFE here.](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/76)

**Workaround**

1. Create a "dummy" vehicle.
2. For all constraints, filter out all assignments to the dummy vehicle.
3. Use HardMediumSoft...Score.
4. Add a constraint to penalize dummy vehicle assignments at 1medium.

**Alternative solution**

We also offers an out-of-the-box, on-prem, paid REST API docker image for [vehicle routing](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-orbit/pkgs/container/orbit-vehicle-routing) that fulfills this and other constraints. (Internally it uses the dummy vehicle workaround too until the RFE is fixed.)